# Upgrading Drupal 7 version from DEV to PROD

Tags: 7, updating

I've updated from Drupal 7.22 to 7.34 on my Development Machine along with some Module updates. Now I am going to update my Production environment.

Question: Do I have to upload the entire root directory or can I just upload the Sites folder? I'm assuming I have to upload the entire root directory as this is a Drupal 7 version core update.

P.S. Got the database update stuff covered.
P.S.S Would use Drush, but I'm just not comfortable with it yet.

Regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

Even thought you said that you are not comfortable with Drush. I would strongly suggest for you to used Drush to update your modules and core. Its just easier and faster. If you decide to give  a try you can update modules and core by running.

```
drush up -y
```

If you want to update just the core use `drush up drupal -y`

You can upload a copy of the latest Drupal version on your production website and then replace sites folder with your dev sites folders. And this would take care of Drupal Core updates.

Comment: That's it? One command?

Comment: There are only a few modules that I want to update, not all.

Comment: Yes, this is going to download all Drupal core and contribute modules updates. This also takes care of the database updates.

Comment: If you want to update just the core use `drush up drupal`

Comment: `drush up drupal -y` This is going to update or Drupal core only.

Comment: Thank you darol100. Just having issues getting to command line on my hosting provider (GreenGeeks). I'll have to contact them for assistance.

Comment: @John you can perform the updates on a local environment. You can download Virtual Machine, Install Ubuntu + Lazy Dubuntu (lazydubuntu.com) and you have an entire local Dev environment. You can perform all updates and then upload on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to keep the core up to date. You will have to replace the updated files of the core which were updated with the fixes.
For e.g. An update from the Drupal version 7.31 to 7.32, which was a fix for the SQL injection issue, changed the following files

1. `includes/database.inc`, and
2. All the info files in the core modules, themes, and profiles.

So, you would need to update all the files. It is strongly recommended to use a code version control system like git when working with Drupal. So that you only need to push the changes and not the complete code again and again. Also, as @darol100 mentioned in his answer, using drush saves a lot of time! So, I would suggest you to spend some time learning it.

For steps on how to update the Drupal core, refer: https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290

Answer (score 1):

If you have stage environment (which should be exact mirror of your prod), you may upgrade your stage environment first (`drush up` or manually) and then once tested, synchronise the files via `rsync`, in example (when having configured drush aliases):

```
drush rsync -vur @stage @prod
```

---

Here is simple script which will deploy the changes from *qa* to *prod* (including the backup):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script to deploy files between remote environments by updating the changed files only.
[ -z "$2" ] && { echo Usage: $0 @remote.src @remote.dst; exit 1; }

DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null)
SRC="$1"
DST="$2"

shift
cd $DIR
drush $DST arb --tags=$DST,$USER
if [ $(drush site-alias --fields=host --format=csv $SRC) = $(drush site-alias --fields=host --format=csv $DST) ]; then
  # Remotes are the same.
  drush $* $DST rsync -vur `drush dd $SRC` @self
else
  # Remotes are not the same.
  drush $* rsync -vur $SRC $DST
```

This script will do the full backup (code, files, and database) before deploying your changes to prod (`arb` = `archive-dump`).  So if your deployment to prod fails, then you can easily restore it (`archive-restore`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do for the site that I've been working on. I have created a git repo to apply changes from dev to prod. I never work on prod, only dev. When I update something, I add those changes to the git repo with the commands `git add -A && git commit -m "your commit message" && git push origin master`. Then I go to prod's docroot, and type `git pull`. Very convenient. You can find out how to create a git repo on [this very useful article](http://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).